# How to get publish value about Python paho Mqtt

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I have a sample code for getting a message from **Mqtt broker**

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
    client.subscribe("123")
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    x = int(msg.payload)*10
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))

client = mqtt.Client()
client.connect("broker.hivemq.com", 1883)
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.loop_forever()
```

How can I get the variable of `msg.payload` in `on_message`?

I add the `x` variable in function of `on_connect`:

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    x = int(msg.payload)*10
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))
    return x
```

**Question:** How do I get the variable `x`?

Comment: `on_message` is a callback function. You can not simply retrieve the return value because it is called implicitly. So, whatever you want to do with `x`, do it inside of the function.

Comment: use a global variable and set its value to x from within the `on_message`

Answer (score 0):

My approach to solve this would be as follows:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
msg_arrived_flag = False
global_X = 0


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
  print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
  client.subscribe("123")
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
  global_X = int(msg.payload)*10
  print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))
  msg_arrived_flag = True

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect("broker.hivemq.com", 1883)

while True:
  client.loop_start()
  time.sleep(5)
  client.loop_stop()
  if msg_arrived_flag:
    msg_arrived_flag = False
    #Use global_X here
```

Time to sleep between start and stop may be set as convenience. Also I suggest to set callbacks before connect. Hope this helps!